# How to display data in Table format with Webchat/Directline channel and .NET SDK?

Tags: botframework

I have a similar question to this one: [microsoft/botframework-sdk#2785](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/2785) but with a different channel and SDK.
I have some table data can be presented in either html or markdown. Is it possible to have it render in bot as a table without implementing my own converter from html/markdown table to ColumnSet?

We're currently using AdaptiveCard with markdown but it's disappointing that adaptive cards doesn't support table with TextBlock. Here's related docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/authoring-cards/text-features

And I also tried sending the table in message directly as below but it doesn't work. So I wonder what's the recommended way to send html/markdown table in bot message?

```
IMessageActivity message = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
message.TextFormat = "xml";
message.Text = xxx;
```

Thanks

Comment: Linking: https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/3506

Comment: You commented in your GitHub issue that you're using Bot Builder v3. Why are you using an outdated version of Bot Builder, and why didn't you mention that important detail in this question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display HTML table inside a chat window with options & buttons in it using Microsoft BOT Framework V4 template using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57800131/how-to-display-html-table-inside-a-chat-window-with-options-buttons-in-it-usin)

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: Hi @KyleDelaney - Thank you for following up. The link you shared is more about converting Html to Markdown and have Webchat UI render it, which is different from our scenario, as we tried rendering message in Markdown format in Bot .NET SDK V3 but not working. And in this [link](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/2289), someone mentioned it works with Bot Node SDK V4. Since we haven't upgraded to .NET SDK V4 so I couldn't verify that. We'll be in the middle of upgrade soon and I'll update once I have the answer.